# When could an uncountable union be reduced to a countable union?

Tags: general-topology

Let $I$ be an uncountable set of indices and $U_\alpha\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be an open subset for each $\alpha\in I$. We know that $U=\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} U_\alpha$ is an open subset.

My question is: does there exist a countable subset $J \subset I$ such that  $U=\bigcup_{\alpha\in J} U_\alpha$?

In general it is not true without the openness condition.

Thanks!

---

As suggested by Chandru, this is a `named' property: Lindelöf space.

Every $\sigma$--compact set is Lindelöf: Let $K_0\subset\cdots K_n\to\subset U$ be an increasing sequence of compact subsets with $\bigcup_{n\ge0}K_n=U$. Each $K_n$ has a finite open cover. So $U$ has a countable open cover.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindel%C3%B6f_space

Comment: Now post it as an answer, wait a while, and eventually accept it. Then the question will not be marked as "unanswered".

Comment: Thanks! Henno's answer is also good enough to be marked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X$ is a topological space, then if this property holds for every open subset of $X$, then this space is called hereditarily Lindelöf. All separable metric spaces have this property, and for metric spaces it's equivalent to separability.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Chandru, this is a `named' property: Lindelöf space.

Every $\sigma$--compact set is Lindelöf: Let $K_0\subset\cdots K_n\to\subset U$ be an increasing sequence of compact subsets with $\bigcup_{n\ge0}K_n=U$. Each $K_n$ has a finite open cover. So $U$ has a countable open cover.